# What did Bruce Banner whisper to General Ross in Hulk #3?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk

In [**Hulk #3 (2008)**](http://marvel.com/comics/issue/20863/hulk_2008_3), Tony Stark is watching video footage of when Doc Samson & General Thaddeus Ross visited Bruce Banner at his cell under Gamma Base. At the end of the visit, Banner whispers something to Ross, and Stark becomes enraged when even the enhanced video cannot distinguish what's being said. As they were leaving Gamma Base, Samson himself asked Ross what Banner told him, and Ross snapped that it was nothing.

Later in the same arc, it was revealed that

> General Ross was in fact the Red Hulk, the very subject being discussed by the three.

**Was it ever revealed what Banner whispered to Ross during this visit? Did Banner somehow already know the identity of the Red Hulk at this time?**

Comment: ["Mapone."](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/48014/5184)

Comment: @phantom42: Aight now...

Comment: Where does the moustache go?